# Receive obj must be an instance or subtype of type when trying to call a class method

Tags: django

I am trying to call a class method  in a view. The method generates a url however when I try call the method using get_context_data I receive 
obj must be an instance or subtype of type when trying to call a class method

## models.py

```
class Scenario(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256, blank=False, null=False, unique=True)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=1000)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('scenarios:detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

    def generate_trade_url(self):
            if self.trade_set.exists():
                return reverse('scenarios:trade-scenario', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
            return None
```

## views.py

```
class Index(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'scenarios/index.html'
    context_object_name = 'all_scenarios'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Scenario.objects.all().order_by('name', 'description')

class Detail(generic.DetailView):
    model = Scenario
    context_object_name = "scenario"
    template_name = 'scenarios/details.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(Scenario, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['tradeurl'] = Scenario.generate_trade_url()
        return context
```

## urls.py

```
 url(r'^$', views.Index.as_view(), name='index'),
 url(r'^(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.Detail.as_view(), name='detail'),
```

## template

```
  <tbody>
                {% for scenario in all_scenarios %}
                <tr>
                    <td><a href ="{% url 'scenarios:detail' scenario.id %}"
                        data-toogle="tooltip" title="Click for filtered view">{{scenario.name}}</a></td>
                    <td>{{scenario.description}}</td>
                    <td>
                        <a href="{% url 'scenarios:scenario-update' scenario.id %}">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" />
                            </button>
                        </a>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <form action="{% url 'scenarios:scenario-delete' scenario.id %}" method="post">
                        {% csrf_token %}
                        <input type="hidden" name="scenario_id" value="{{ scenario.id}}"/>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete {{scenario.name}}?')">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" />
                        </button>
                        </form>
                    </td>
                </tr>

            {% endfor %}
            </tbody>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you're not calling the method on the specific instance of this model, but the class instead. Simply put: if you don't care about the DB values that this instance of this class contains, you can call either a static or a class method (both having their pros/cons, but you can find info about them elsewhere). If you do care about the DB values of this instance (your case, it seems), then you have to call a bound method of the class.

So how?

Well, just FYI, static and class methods can be created and called like this:

```
class Something(object):
    CONSTANT_A = '123'    

    @classmethod
    def my_class_method(cls):
         return cls.CONSTANT_A * 123

    @staticmethod
    def my_static_method():
        return 'static value' # or duplicate the previous method: return Something.CONSTANT_A * 123

a = Something()
class_method_value = a.my_class_method()
static_method_value = Something.my_static_method()
```

For the use case that you have, you need a bound method and that's exactly what you have there, but the way you wall it is a bit off. You need an instance of the class (with DB values), not the class itself. In the view you can achieve it like this:

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    value_that_you_want = self.object.generate_trade_url()
```

If you don't have the `self.object` variable at some point, then one way to get the model instance, is to query it from the database. I.e. `Detail.objects.get(id=1)`.

Good luck.

Comment: The following worked
`def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    #     context = super(Detail, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    #     context['trade_url'] = self.object.generate_trade_url()`

However.. I ended up scrapping it and using an iFrame in my template which ended up doing the job with a number of lines less